How to create a string with words separated by double quotes and commas
In a dataframe I have a column with names. I want to transform these names into a string to pass as a variable in a sql query.
I need the names to be separated with ",". For example "a","b","c","d".
df <- data.frame(names=c("a","b","c","d"))

The best I got was
df2 <- paste0('"',paste0(df$names,collapse=',"','"'))
cat(df2)
"a","b","c","d"> 

But there is this ">" at the end.
So, is it possible to get "a","b","c","d" from df$names?
The SQL query is something like
sql.query <- paste0("
    SELECT field1,field2
    FROM mytable
    WHERE field1 IN (",df2,");
    ")  
    

Thanks

I'm not able to duplicate the problem you're having. There's no > when I run this code...

Use sprintf.  For the inserted string first process with dQuote and toString.
sprintf("
  SELECT field1,field2
  FROM mytable
  WHERE field1 IN (%s);
", toString(dQuote(df$name))) |> cat()

giving
  SELECT field1,field2
  FROM mytable
  WHERE field1 IN (“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”);


To get rid of the > at the end, you can try this:
df <- data.frame(names = c("a","b","c","d"))
df2 <- paste0('"', paste(df$names, collapse = '","'), '"')
cat(df2)

This gives "a","b","c","d"
Now you can use df2 like this:
sql.query <- paste0("
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM mytable
    WHERE field1 IN (", df2, ");
")

cat(sql.query)


The > isn't part of the output - it's the terminal/command line indicator for entering the next command. I see the same thing as you do using RGui or Emacs/ESS.
RGui

Emacs/ESS

If you look closely, you'll notice the > is even a different colour to the output text.
